# cron job not running - root runs ok tho

Tags: bash, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a script I just created which runs fine under root.  I added a cron job but it doesn't run right

Commands are:

```
gpio -g mode 17 input
getval="$(gpio read 17)"
todayis=$(date) 
getstatus=$getval 
if [ "$getstatus" = "0"  ]; then 
power="Power ON"
else
power="Power OFF"
echo $todayis $power $getstatus >> /var/www/turnmeon.log
```

Log file when run as root:

```
Wed Nov 8 21:11:41 UTC 2017 Power ON 0
```

Log file when run as crontab:

```
Wed Nov 8 21:11:41 UTC 2017 Power OFF
```

There is no 1 at the end like I might expect if OFF really was true.

Why would it run under a bash prompt but not as a crontab job

```
*/2 * * * * bash /myscript.sh
```

Comment: You may want to read [the reference question at Server Fault about debugging cronjobs](https://serverfault.com/q/449651/313521).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's a permission issue.  You're probably editing the crontab as your desktop user, which means tasks will run under the desktop user.  You need to edit the crontab as root if the task requires root

Comment: it's only a shell install - from root im running crontab -e

Comment: are you sure?  add `whoami >> /var/www/turnmeon.log` to the end of your script

Comment: confirmed to be running as root - weird

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause is that `gpio` isn't in the `PATH` available in cron. Specify the full path to your gpio command, such as

```
getval="$(/sbin/gpio read 17)"
```

Find out where it is on your system using `which gpio`.

I got bitten by this before because I tinker with embedded solutions a lot. If the script is more complex, I usually initialize PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH near the start to make things easier.